# Show that $(p(\text{not } B) - p(\text{not } A \cap \text{ not } B))/p(A) = 1-p(B|A)$.

Tags: probability

$\newcommand{\not}{\operatorname{not}}$
I have this equation:

> $$\frac{p(\not B) - p(\not A \cap \not B)}{p(A)} = 1-p(B|A)$$

The book says:

- $p(A) > 0$
- not $A$ is the opposite of $A$
- not $B$ is the opposite of $B$
- $p(B| A)$ is the probability of $B$ if $A$

So far I've done:

\begin{align*}
\frac{p(\not B) - p(\not A \cap \not B)}{p(A)} &=
\frac{(1-p(B)) - \not p(A \cup B)}{p(A)}  \\
&=\frac{-p(B) + p (A \cup B)}{p(A)}\\
&=\ ?
\end{align*}
What do I do next? Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\not}{\operatorname{not}}$

> $ P(\not A \cap \not B) = \not P(A \cup B)$

False. You cannot "factor" a $\not$ like this. Instead, we use DeMorgan's law and get
$$P(\not A\cap \not B) = 1-P(\not(\not A\cap\not B)) = 1-P(A\cup B).$$

\begin{align*}
\frac{P(\not B) - P(\not A \cap \not B)}{P(A)}&=\frac{[1-P(B)]-[1-P(A\cup B)]}{P(A)} \\
&=\frac{1-P(B)-[1-[P(A)+P(B)-P(AB)]]}{P(A)} \tag 1\\
&=\frac{P(A)-P(AB)}{P(A)}\\
&=1-P(B|A)
\end{align*}
where in $(1)$ I used inclusion-exclusion and the last line is true by definition.

Comment: What I don't understand is how the line before (1) becomes (P(A)-P(AB))/P(A). Do you just cut out the +1 -1 and the -P(B) +P(B)?

Comment: Yes, I cut some basic steps.

Comment: I see. Thanks for answering